# Does this site want to succeed?

Tags: discussion

So I posted a question [Push-ups at the office, more often or more at once?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24591) it was almost immediately closed as off topic (*apparently doing things to stay healthy are not in scope*).

So I went [looking in Meta](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=topic) for what made it off topic. I found 82 posts containing "topic" there are only 370 questions on the site.  That implies for every existing question on the main page there are 4.5 posts in meta about what is on topic.

Earlier today I came across [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283) which was just to depressing to read.

In my experience here, there has been a lot of negativity; down votes, not happy about this or that. To me it feels like the community is trying to set such high standards and narrow scope that it is strangling it's self.

It might be a bit early in the launch to be discouraging participation (IMHO). What is the goal of this proposal and how do you expect to reach it?

Do you want to be greatest site on the internet for all thing related to Health? Or do you want to be the place where a few answer to a few questions can be found.

Answer (score 4):

You ask several questions.

> In my experience here, there has been a lot of negativity; down votes, not happy about this or that. To me it feels like the community is trying to set such high standards and narrow scope that it is strangling it's self.

You can change that by asking good questions, posting good answers, leaving comments on how questions can be improved, upvoting, etc. It's as much your community as it is for anyone else.

You've asked 11 questions, posted 2 answers, and received 46 up votes (as well as some down votes). You have given only 11 up votes. If that's a reflection of your opinion of the quality of the questions here, then ask better ones. But try to be on topic.

> It might be a bit early in the launch to be discouraging participation (IMHO).

It's never too early to encourage good questions and answers, and to define the scope of the site. That is done by everyone as well. You have a reopen vote. Feel free to use it! If the community agrees with you, a question will be reopened.

> What is the goal of this proposal and how do you expect to reach it? Do you want to be greatest site on the internet for all thing related to Health? Or do you want to be the place where a few answer to a few questions can be found.

The question has been asked on meta before. Hopefully, the users who ask and answer on this site know that issues are much more complex than those presented by way of a false dichotomy (a logical fallacy which involves presenting two opposing views in such a way that they seem to be the only possibilities.) No one here wants a *meh* site. On the other hand, in order to  have a good site, a *lot* of decisions, a *lot* of good questions, and a *lot* of good answers (among other things) will be required.

To be honest, your post seems to be more of a negative emotional reaction to a legitimate migration than a discussion of the problems new sites face. If you have valid suggestions for discussion, this is the right place to post them.

Comment: This answer assumes that the migration was legitimate, which would be the subject of different discussion.  It attempts to focus the point on my participation, rather the the focus of the question which is the site about the site.  As this answer attacks the person asking the question rather then addressing the concerns raised, enough said there.

Comment: Maybe you should ask your self why only moderators have chosen to address this question.  Also consider that [The ideal moderator does as little as possible](http://health.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) which is clearly not evident in the handling of the question which you seem to feel is the only concern (other than me?).

Comment: You posted a question about your migrated question, followed by a dismal assessment of the site. I don't follow your implication about moderators answering a question about migration, which is a moderator's job. I've addressed your other issues. The ideal community does mostly govern itself, but not without mods. Again, only mods can migrate between sites. Finally, meta is a place where (I was under the impression, perhaps erroneous) that a mod is expected to participate more fully. Mod or not, I would have given the same answer about your false dichotomy.

Answer (score 1):

I was the one that migrated it. You have to choose it being an off topic question for it to be eligible for migration.

While it is within the scope for this site, I felt that it would get better attention and answers on the Fitness SE since it was about increasing your fitness to combat sedentary lifestyle elements. Yes, the final question was "which is healthier", but the entire focus of the question was on the exercise elements.

We have known all along that there would be some crossover elements with fitness and biology, where there would be questions that could be on either site. There have been some fitness and nutrition question on the Fitness SE that have been migrated here as well.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.