# Why did my comment get deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

I had left a comment on the question [Does this site want to succeed?](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295/does-this-site-want-to-succeed) but it got deleted. Why?

Comment: What was it saying?

Comment: @Shlubu I don't have access to it anymore but it was pointing to two other meta posts.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254038/191655) may help. After posting on this site, archive the page by going to `http://web.archive.org/save/http://full_url_here`, you'll have the backup just in case. I'm thinking to write some Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script which will do that automatically when posting on this site as it seems a lot of things are removed from here too often for not clear reasons.

Comment: @kenorb, Please do let me know when you have done an archival tool specific for SE sites. For the time being, I'm using both web.archive.org and [archive.is](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18651/web-service-that-serves-as-public-proof-that-a-given-url-contains-something-at-a/18667#comment27164_18651).

Comment: Thank you, I am livid that a moderator deleted one of my constructive comments, saying I shouldn't answer in a comment, and now I'm supposed to retype that comment because it's deleted when I could have simply copied and pasted it and THEN deleted the comment? Moderators need to have more respect for people's time and efforts.

Comment: @sss4r user-content on Stack Exchange = toilet paper. And silently flushed down. [When a user has one of his question or answer deleted, why don't you notify him about the deletion, and send the removed content by email?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209694/178179)

Comment: @sss4r the current policy is [delete all the answer in the comment](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/378/99). So you need to make your answer as an answer. It is because (bad) comments cannot be downvoted.

Comment: @kenorb i love your effort

Comment: @Ooker I believe the policy has been changed 5 min ago to 'deletion should be reserved for spam' (as the most voted answer).

Answer (score 4):

It was just a routine cleanup of a misplaced comment. The comment was essentially just saying "+1" followed by a list of some meta posts you had also written. There isn't much more to it than that.

If someone has an answer or would otherwise like to respond to something being discussed, they should post it posted below as an *answer.* I can appreciate that sometimes folks don't really have an "answer" but want to jump into the conversation nonetheless. But comments were not designed to be the mini chat room or discussion section of Stack Exchange, so if a comment is not seeking clarification or otherwise suggesting improvements to the post, they are subject to being removed. It's just the way we keep the right tools being used for the right job.

Comment: Are you saying that any comment posted with the intent of giving some links related to the question should be deleted?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt No, I see folks saying "we've already discussed parts of this <here>", no problem. If your links were somehow directly related to the question being discussed, I failed to see that. It looked to me more a random aside: *As long as we're going to air broad grievances, here is some other stuff you can read.* If there was a stronger connection than that, it didn't come across in the comment... which is why comments are not good for discussions in general.

Comment: My links were related to "In my experience here, there has been a lot of negativity; down votes, not happy about this or that. To me it feels like the community is trying to set such high standards and narrow scope that it is strangling it's self.".

Comment: If @FranckDernoncourt is right, isn't his comment for adding relevant information?

Comment: @Ooker He'll never reply since the comment shouldn't have been removed since it did add relevant information.