# Why didn't these +1 comments get deleted?

Tags: discussion, flagging, comments

I flagged these two +1 comments for deletion:

> +1 - This answer could not be any better. Great information and references
>
> Couldn't agree more. This is one of the best answers I've seen! Should be the accepted answer.

but it got declined:

[image]

According to [this post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/305/43),  comments that are essentially just saying "+1" should be deleted.

Why did my flags for deletion get declined?

Comment: This only further supports [this theory](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/325/114). I guess we need more experienced people here.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, this again.

So you're mad your comment was deleted. And rather than defending the merits of *your* comment (or, y'know, learning something and changing your behavior), you're throwing a tantrum by flagging others' comments in hope of demonstrating some sort of inconsistency.

Well, you missed the biggest inconsistency of them all then: you didn't flag two comments, **you flagged eight of them.** And all but two were marked as "helpful".

Here, let's all have an honest screenshot:

[image]

There. That's your *actual* flag history, with ~78% of comment flags marked helpful, 75% of those regarding "+1" comments marked helpful. Does this demonstrate inconsistency? Maybe. Does it matter? No, not in the slightest.

**Because you completely missed the key part of the answer you're quoting.**

> [If someone has an answer or would otherwise like to respond to something being discussed, they should post it posted below as an answer.](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302/why-did-my-comment-get-deleted/305#305)

The deleted comment you're so sore about was on meta; the comments you've flagged are not. The deleted comment you're so sore about was apparently an attempt to express agreement with a meta post by way of a related post of your own; the comments you've flagged are not. The right thing for you to do in response to being asked to post an answer responding to the meta discussion would've been **to post an answer responding to the meta discussion.** Instead you went and flagged a bunch of irrelevant comments somewhere else.

*slow clap*

Comment: I think you are making a lot of assumptions… I just wanted to point out the inconsistency, or understand why it was consistent in case I missed something. My deleted comment is another subject. We are talking about the +1 comments here, chill down.

Comment: I prefer the term "educated guess". I'm right, you know I'm right, and now you desperately want to talk about something that doesn't matter... Well, go right ahead.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm in no way saying you are wrong, and I've never had your position (or say had to be a 6th grade teacher among other things I've heard moding compared to...), but this came across as quite combative and negative.  Maybe that's what was called for here, but I think the spirit of SE involves a more constructive way to do it?  Anyway thanks for being a mod, I can't imagine it's easy.

Comment: Not a fan of humoring people who respond to guidance by essentially mocking the person who tried to guide them, @Atl. Robert's answer (referenced in the question here and in all eight flags) was a sincere attempt to explain why a certain action was taken and offer a useful alternative; pretending to understand that as an invitation to launch a mass flagging campaign is, in my humble opinion, quite rude and I see no good reason to play along with it.

Comment: @Shog9 just put in your answer whether +1 comments should be deleted or not, that's what my question is about, not kindergarten fights.

Comment: You're lumping (at least) two completely different comments into a single broad category and asking for an answer that applies to both without regard for nuance or context, @Franck. No, you can't have that.

Comment: @Shog9 it is fine with me if you don't answer the question but then please don't pollute the page.